# Catch an error and reject the promise

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I need to catch an error and reject the promise chain below.

How can this

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
deferred.resolve();

deferred.then(function () {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch (err) {
    return $.Deferred().reject();
  }
}).then(function () {
  console.log('success', arguments);
}, function () {
  console.log('fail', arguments);
});
```

be made rejected in jQuery? I would expect `fail`, but there is `success`.

Comment: Which version of jQuery ?

Comment: @guest271314 I guess it was an answer, mine was just too old (1.7). Do you have an idea when they fixed promises? Is the code in the answer more fail-proof (still won't work at 1.7 though).

Comment: Not certain about meaning of _"Is the code in the answer more fail-proof"_ ? From documentation http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ , changes were made to `deferred.then()`  at 1.8  http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/ http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010

Comment: The code from the question seems to be workable as well in 1.8. Thank you! I'm no longer despise jQuery deferreds that much.

Comment: @estus they're still pretty bad until 3.0, which actually fixes them to be "real" promises.

Comment: @estus: The code in guest's answer is no better than your original one (only longer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery version 1.8 , see [deferred.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) , [jQuery 1.8 Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) , [MAKE DEFERRED.THEN == DEFERRED.PIPE LIKE PROMISE/A](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010)

```js
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
deferred.resolve();

deferred.then(function () {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch (err) {
    return $.Deferred().reject();
  }
}).then(function () {
  console.log('success', arguments);
}, function () {
  console.log('fail', arguments);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @estus See updated post. Correct answer is use version 1.8 or greater of jQuery.